Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in reactjs and nodejs
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
i tried to decode it in backend and it doesnt getting resolved instead its jumping to catch block. i tried to resolve but unable to do so
my UserProfile.js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../../App';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserProfile = ({ match }) => {
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
    const userId = useParams()
    useEffect(() => {
        
        fetch(`/user/${userId}`, {
            method:"GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(result => {
            setUserProfile(result);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "750px", margin: "0px auto" }}>
            {userProfile ?
                <div>
                    <div style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "space-around",
                        margin: "18px 0px",
                        borderBottom: '1px solid gray'
                    }}>
                        <div>
                            <img style={{ width: "160px", height: "160px", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8aHVtYW4lMjBwcm9maWxlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww"
                                alt="profile" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>{userProfile.user.name}</h4>
                            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", width: "108%" }}>
                                <h6>{userProfile.posts.length} Posts</h6>
                                {/* You can add Followers and Following counts here if needed */}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='gallery'>
                        {userProfile.posts.map(item => {
                            return (
                                <img key={item._id} className="item" src={item.photo} alt="posts" />
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
                : <h2>Loading...</h2>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserProfile;


my user.js //backend
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const requireLogin = require('../middleware/requireLogin'); // Middleware to check authentication
const User = mongoose.model("User");
const Post = mongoose.model("Post");


// Endpoint to fetch user profile details
router.get('/user/:userId', requireLogin, (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId })
        .select("-password") // Exclude password field
        .then(user => {
            Post.find({ postedBy: req.params.userId })
                .populate("postedBy", "_id name") // Populate user details in posts
                .then(( posts) => {
                    res.json({ user, posts });
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
        });
});

module.exports = router;



Check at the backend by doing this res.status(404).json({ error: err }); what specific error your are getting?Most likely Post.find query failed and it is not getting catched that is why you are getting Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token...

Please provide a (shorter) minimal reproducible example if possible.

A few observations and comments:
a) First of all, there needs to be a catch clause added in the code below. Besides that, when the server returns 404, it must be checked separately. Otherwise the json object returned with 404 code will be mistakenly used as data. As a result, setUserProfile will be invoked with an invalid data. Both of these points have been conceived in the revised code below.
fetch(...)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(result => {
        setUserProfile(result);
    });

Revised code
fetch(...)
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response status :${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => setUserProfile(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log('custome error' + error));

b) Now the reason for the backend error 404 is that, it seems there is a cast error happens in the below statement. Please include the err object in response so that it will be notified to the backend.
 User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId })
 ...
 .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
        });

Revised code
 ...
 .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found", reason: err });
        });

c) There needs to be a return and a catch code to add in the below statement.
router.get('/user/:userId', requireLogin, (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId })
        .select("-password") // Exclude password field
        .then(user => {
            // return added
            return Post.find({ postedBy: req.params.userId })
                .populate("postedBy", "_id name") // Populate user details in posts
                .then(( posts) => {
                    res.json({ user, posts });
                })//catch added
               .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "Post not found" });

});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
        });
});

Lastly, I am not able to figure out the reason for the error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE ". Once the above three points are addressed, the reason for this error may be made more visible.
